# What do you call a person who dies an honourable death?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

What do you call someone who dies for a good cause or an honourable reason?

An example would be a soldier who dies while saving his country.

Answer (score 2):

A *martyr*. While the word *hero* could also be used, it can happen that the hero does an honorable thing and survives, while the word *martyr* always signifies that the person died.

Comment: Interesting case, these two words, of how far words travel from their origins: in early Greek (where both words originated), a *hero* was always someone who had died, while a *martyr* just meant one who bore witness, who might well survive. And speaking of ancient Greece, a very Greek answer would be *happy* or *blest* (ὄλβιος): see [Herodotus 1.30](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D30)-32, Sophocles [*OT* 1529-30](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0192%3Acard%3D1516), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a word *martyr* here:

meaning:

> a person who suffers very much or is killed because of their religious
>   or political beliefs , and is often **admired** because of it:
>
> a Christian / Islamic / religious martyr
>
> She fought against racism all her life and died a martyr to the cause

Other words could be: a war hero, man of courage, man of the hour, conquering hero, ,*lionheart* (as in *Braveheart* film. The hero dies at the end of the film)

Comment: This doesn’t quite feel right to me, and I’m trying to figure out why.  A father who saves his entire family from their burning home but himself perishes in the effort is not a “martyr”, although he is unquestionably a fallen hero.

Comment: @tchrist I bet we can call that person a martyr too (A father who saves his entire family from their burning home but himself perishes in the effort).

Answer (score 1):

You would say that such people had sacrificed themselves for the sake of others.  That’s fine as a verb because it is used reflexively.

The problem with saying that they were “a sacrifice” as a noun is that it suggests they were sacrificed by someone else rather than giving up their lives for others.

Correcting this leads to the noun ***self-sacrifice***, which the OED defines as:

> Sacrifice of oneself; the giving up of one’s own interests, happiness, and desires, for the sake of duty or the welfare of others.
>
> - **1805** Wordsw. *Poems Sentim., Ode to Duty* 54 ― Give unto me, made lowly wise, The spirit of self-sacrifice.
>
>   **1843** Kingsley *Lett.* (1878) I. 101 ― What a strange mystery is that of mutual self-sacrifice! to exist for one moment for another.
>
>   **1885** J. Martineau *Types Eth. Th.* I. i. i. §7. 226 ― Absolute self-sacrifice of the passions and imagination.

The OED also provides a bunch of derived terms that stem from *self-sacrifice*:

> So ****self-ˈsacrificed**** *pa. pple.*; ****self-ˈsacrificer****, a self-sacrificing person; ****self-sacriˈficial**** *a.* = next; ****self-ˈsacrificing**** *ppl. a.*, making a sacrifice of one’s life, etc. (whence ****‑ˈsacrificingly**** *adv.*, ****‑ˈsacrificingness****).
>
>   **A. 1711** Ken *Preparatives* Poet. Wks. IV. 83 ― *Self-sacrific’d, his Father’s Will, And our Redemption to fulfil.
>
>   **1900** *Inscr. in Postmen’s Park, Aldersgate St., London*, ― Mary Rogers, stewardess of the Stella, March 30, 1899, self-sacrificed by giving up her life-belt, and voluntarily going down in the sinking ship.
>
>   **1668** H. More *Div. Dial.* iii. xxv. I. 467 ― Martyrs and *Self-sacrificers to but so faint a Shadow··of the first uncreated Perfection.
>
>   **1903** *Sat. Rev.* 4 Apr. 421/2 ― It is usual for the self-sacrificer to be a consistently melodramatic person.
>
>   **1855** Bailey *Mystic*, etc. 98 ― The painful pelican *Self-sacrificial.
>
>   **1893** H. R. Reynolds in *Life* (1898) 473 ― Your self-sacrificial love to a great duty.
>
>   **1817** Moore *Lalla Rookh, Parad. & Peri* (ed. 2) 149 ― That precious sigh Of pure, *self-sacrificing love.
>
>   **1897** Gladstone *E. Crisis* 14 ― In the midst of a high and self-sacrificing enthusiasm, the Greek Government and people have shown good sense.
>
>   **1882** *Advance* (Chicago) 5 Oct., ― *Self-sacrificingly non-denominational in all directions.
>
>   **1871** Smiles *Charac.* ix. (1876) 239 ― In *self-sacrificingness,··in the ordinary intercourse of life, mainly consists the difference between being well and ill bred.